# Undefined method 'perform_caching' when doing fragment caching with JBuilder and Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, jbuilder

I'm trying to apply fragment caching to one of my jbuilder views:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

json.cache!(['1', @countries], expires_in: 60.minutes) do
  json.partial!('country', collection: @countries, as: :country)
end
```

Unfortunately this outputs the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `perform_caching' for #<Api::CountriesController:0x00005572a6187f90>):
  1: # frozen_string_literal: true
  2: 
  3: json.cache!(['1', @countries], expires_in: 60.minutes) do
  4:   json.partial!('country', collection: @countries, as: :country)
  5: end
```

I've added the following gems to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem "actionpack-page_caching", "~> 1.2"
gem "actionpack-action_caching", "~> 1.2"
```

In my `application.rb` I've added the following lines:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
```

What else is necessary to enable fragment caching in jbuilder views?

I'm on Rails 6.0.2 with jbuilder 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to include `ActionController::Caching` to your base controller `ApplicationController` as it's not included in `ActionController::API`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API                                                    
  include ActionController::Caching
  # ...
end
```

or you might only include it in `Api::CountriesController` if you wish to use caching only in this controller

see https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/331

I also believe you do not need the additional gems

```
gem "actionpack-page_caching", "~> 1.2"
gem "actionpack-action_caching", "~> 1.2"
```